# PHP - Convert Youtube URL to Embed URL

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I am trying to convert a standard Youtube URL to an Embed URL with the following function:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVT78QcRQtU';

function getYoutubeEmbedUrl($url)
{
    $shortUrlRegex = '/youtu.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\??/i';
    $longUrlRegex = '/youtube.com\/((?:embed)|(?:watch))((?:\?v\=)|(?:\/))(\w+)/i';

    if (preg_match($longUrlRegex, $url, $matches)) {
        $youtube_id = $matches[count($matches) - 1];
    }

    if (preg_match($shortUrlRegex, $url, $matches)) {
        $youtube_id = $matches[count($matches) - 1];
    }
    return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $youtube_id ;
}

getYoutubeEmbedUrl();
```

However when running it I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function getYoutubeEmbedUrl()
```

I am not understand why I have too few arguments when I only have one and I supplied it??

[Online Editable Demo](http://syframework.alwaysdata.net/6jw)

Comment: The short url regex will not catch all youtube urls, as some have dashes in them and the regex will cut them off. Here's a fixed regex to work with dashes: $shortUrlRegex = '/youtu.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)\??/i';

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define a function in PHP, non global variables are **not** accessible within the function.

Therefore you have to provide the URL as **parameter** of the function (which you've defined as `$url`).

Working solution:

```
<?php

function getYoutubeEmbedUrl($url){
    $shortUrlRegex = '/youtu.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\??/i';
    $longUrlRegex = '/youtube.com\/((?:embed)|(?:watch))((?:\?v\=)|(?:\/))(\w+)/i';

    if (preg_match($longUrlRegex, $url, $matches)) {
        $youtube_id = $matches[count($matches) - 1];
    }

    if (preg_match($shortUrlRegex, $url, $matches)) {
        $youtube_id = $matches[count($matches) - 1];
    }
    return 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $youtube_id ;
}


$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVT78QcRQtU';
$embeded_url = getYoutubeEmbedUrl($url);

echo $embeded_url;
```

---

> I am not understand why I have too few arguments when I only have one and I supplied it??

A argument of a `PHP` function always has to be supplied via the method call. Predefined variables are not used by the function.

Comment: Great, thank you for explaining. I will accept as an answer when the time is up.

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't pass the argument when you execute the function "getYoutubeEmbedUrl()" on the last line.

try "echo getYoutubeEmbedUrl($url);"